# Content in textareas set to use nicEdit not updating to reflect user changes

Tags: jquery, edit, nicedit

Accept my apologize because of my low English level

I use to load a page with jQuery and I use nicEdit in that page and I post datas to another page with jQuery.  But it just send empty value instead of what user wrote in editor (if i define a default value for my text area, it just send the default value not the text wrote by user).  What is the problem and what is the solution?

Thanks.

---

***UPDATE*** After reading [this related article](http://www.netshinesoftware.com/component/option,com_myblog/Itemid,65/show,Capturing-content-from-nicEdit-when-form-is-submitted-by-javascript.html/) and it's comments at end and reading other articles i found must use this way before submiting form :

```
nicEditors.findEditor('textarea_id').saveContent();
```

For this i use jquery to select any textarea and call `.each()` jquery function. For example :

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
   var IDOfThisTextArea =   $(this).attr('id');
   nicEditors.findEditor(IDOfThisTextArea).saveContent()
});
```

This work fine for textarea that created beforehand.  But I have some textarea that created dynamically via jQuery that `findEditor()` function above didn't found those and not call `saveContent()` for those.

For this problem what you offer??????

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer for dynamically created elements is to use something like `$('selector').on('click', function(...))` or whathaveyou to dynamically bind to the the triggering action, have that `function` body find any relevant `.nice-wrapper textarea`s (via sensible selectors) as a jquery object `$textareas`, and prior to executing the submit

```
 $textareas.each(function(){ 
  nicEditors.findEditor(this.id).saveContent();
 });
```

which will then let you use some of the convenience methods like `.serializeArray`.  Obviously, there are many different ways to solve this problem - e.g., perhaps you want to bind to the submit event of the form instead of to a click on a button - but I'd think many (most?) of the sensible solutions fall into the same general category.

Answer (score 3):

What about saving all instances like this before you submit the form

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function () {
    for(var i=0;i<nicEditors.nicInstances.length;i++){
        nicEditors.nicInstances[i].saveContent();
    }
});
```